# Keep external JARs outside the project JAR while creating product in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My eclipse project structure is as given below 
->MyProject 
-->JRE System Lib
-->plugin dependencies
-->src
-->extJars (contains some external JARs)
-->icons(contains icons files)
-->META-INF
-->build.properties
-->plugin.xml
-->Myproject.product

When I export MyProject as a product using Eclipse MyProject.product, complete files in MyProject including ExtJars and icons get bundled as a single JAR file.
MyProject/plugins/**MyProject_1.0.0.0.jar**

I want extJars and icons to be kept outside that single JAR file.

Kindly help me in achieving this.

Thank You

Comment: There are ways to access objects in a plugin jar as ordinary files if required. Depending on exactly what you want to do that may be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ['features'](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html) to build your product you can use the 'unpack the plug-in archive after the installation' option in the 'feature.xml' to have the plug-in expanded when it is installed.

Comment: I want only those two folders to be kept outside, remaining has to be in JAR only.

Comment: Kindly give me some links to read how to work with features in the buld

Comment: To the best of my knowledge that can't be done. Added link in answer to features tutorial. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html